# Python Pyserial write() in Putty then STM32

Tags: python, stm32, hardware, pyserial

Im trying to see what pyserial is writing in Putty, later on I would like to try CubeIDE STM32 to receive this data as well.

Putty gives me a port is being used error. How can I check what Python is writing to COM5?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use programs like for example Virtual Serial Port Driver. It can create linked virtual COM ports ,one to write and second to read data.